# Forward Telegram Channel Messages to Twitter via Bot (with delay)

Tags: javascript, python, php, mysql, django

Hope you are having a good time. I am looking to develop a basic telegram bot that will redirect all the messages from a private telegram channel to a twitter account with a delay of 3 hours, that is, if a message is posted in a telegram channel at 09:00 AM it should be forwarded to twitter at 12:00 AM. Can it be possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this would be possible with a Python package/wrapper for the Telegram API. [Python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) looks like a very popular and extended package for the job. Here's a link to the ["Your first Bot" page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot).

To fetch tweets you could use the Twitter API (you do need a key, last time I checked it could take a while for them to give you one). There's also Python wrappers for this like [Tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/getting_started.html).